# Angular: Calling function that changes scope variable on interval

Tags: angularjs

I've built a function that does some text transformations on a string. I'm calling this function from my view.

I would now like to call this function from a controller with a set interval,every 3 seconds.

I was trying with this in my controller:

```
$scope.MyTextFunction = function(input) {
    cancelRefresh = $timeout(function myFunction(input) {
        console.log(input);
        // Do things here
        cancelRefresh = $timeout(myFunction, 3000);
    },3000);
};
```

I'm having some trouble getting this to work. Specifically, it seems all the functions that are called in the view are being triggered again. So console.log(input) gets called 4 times, then 8 times, then 16 times, etc, every 3 seconds. (I'm guessing this is due to the digest cycle? I'm not totally clear on this).

As you can expect, after staying on this view for 20 seconds the browser becomes unresponsive.

How can I make write a function that

1. triggers every 3 seconds,
2. is tied to the scope so I can use the output in the view and
3. doesn't trigger all the existing functions that already exist in the view?

I've set up a plunkr that contains the text transformation string: http://plnkr.co/edit/JlEBlCBG3roCqkiKegI6?p=preview

Comment: Use $interval.  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Was looking for slightly more information than that. The example in the documentation is exceedingly complex for this my use case. Best explanation on Angular's $interval function I've come across so far is this video by Joe Maddalone: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFxPFgGaEqk

Comment: What kind of information?  Does this help? http://plnkr.co/edit/Z03Y6AFXFth9wW6fztjF

Comment: How often is $scope.MyTextFunction getting called?  Each time, that would create a new timer and cause more executions.  That's probably where your increasing number of calls is coming from.  Can you post a bit more of your code or maybe a plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey @CraigSquire I've just added a plunkr.

Comment: Ha, I got it! Forgot $interval (like regular js interval) doesn't take an input, so had to wrap it in an anonymous function. Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: I used this solution and it work good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324694/interval-function-continues-when-i-change-routes